# code causing a 1004 error and im not sure why

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, syntax-highlighting

So i have this string of code that should let me auto highlight rows and columns of active cells... The catch is it is popping a 1004 error and I'm not sure why. Possibly in the syntax?

It flags the ".colorindex=20"

Im running excel 2010

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Static rr
Static cc

If cc <> "" Then
    With Columns(cc).Interior
        .ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With
    With Rows(rr).Interior
        .ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With
End If

r = Selection.Row
c = Selection.Column
rr = r
cc = c

With Columns(c).Interior
    .ColorIndex = 20
    .Pattern = xlSolid
End With
With Rows(r).Interior
    .ColorIndex = 20
    .Pattern = xlSolid
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This means `c` is an invalid number. Throw `Debug.Print c` before the line `With Columns(c).Interior` to f ind out what the value of `c` is.

Comment: I added that line and it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Is your Immediates window turned on? `Ctrl+G` in the VBE or click View->Immediate Window from the menu.

Comment: Is now... it came back with 10 listen in the box.

Comment: Then there's your problem. `10 listen` is not a valid column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add :

```
Dim r, c
```

the code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Static rr
Static cc
Dim r, c

If cc <> "" Then
    With Columns(cc).Interior
        .ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With
    With Rows(rr).Interior
        .ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With
End If

r = Selection.Row
c = Selection.Column
rr = r
cc = c

With Columns(c).Interior
    .ColorIndex = 20
    .Pattern = xlSolid
End With
With Rows(r).Interior
    .ColorIndex = 20
    .Pattern = xlSolid
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: It works without dimming r and c (since his code sample didn't include `Option Explicit`). His issue is that his actual code is setting `c` to a non-numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Solved... had to edit the colors in this format. and then she ran... my only catch to it is it is now reformatting the colors I already have on the sheet.

Is there a work around to that from the original code to where it highlight but doesnt reformat?

```
With Columns(c).Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 10937227
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
With Rows(r).Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 10937227
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
End Sub
```